# AndroidStudio - Fragment overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button, overlapping

Yesterday, I came across a problem that concerns "propably" fragments overlapping. I have a fragment **(A)** with **RecyclerView & FloatingActionButton**. There is **onClickListener** set to that **FAB**, which should replace the whole fragment **(A)** view with fragment **(B)**. Unfortunately **FAB** somehow stays on top, but **RecyclerView** is exchanged with fragment **(B)** view. I'm almost sure that I'm replacing container with both **RV** & **FAB**. Maybe any ideas where should I look for solution?

Navigation code:

```
private void onNavigate(int container,Fragment fragment, boolean backStack, Integer animIn, Integer animOut){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(animIn,animOut,animIn,animOut);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(container,fragment);

        if(backStack){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Fragment Replacing:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);
    FB_addTask = view.findViewById(R.id.fb_addTask_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

    FB_addTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           getNavigationListener().onNagivate(R.id.tab1_content,new Tab1_AddTask_Fragment(),true,R.anim.anim_from_left_to_right,R.anim.anim_from_center_to_left);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab1_content"
    android:background="@color/Grey_300"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_addTask_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_dark_blue"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/SC_Gold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If your code really says `onNagivate()`, it shouldn't compile. If not, please post your actual code.

Comment: I'm overriding onNavigate() method so there is no problem with that :)

Comment: I don't understand. A method that overrides `onNavigate()` would be called `onNavigate()`. But instead you have `onNagivate()`. Where is the code for `onNagivate()`?